# Vert.x WebClient - GET request over HTTPS fails on Ubuntu server with null cause

Tags: java, ssl, https, vert.x

I'm trying to send a GET request over HTTPS using Vert.x Web client `3.5.0` (and Java 8).

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
WebClientOptions clientOptions = new WebClientOptions();
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, clientOptions);
Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponse<Buffer>>> testHandler = asyncResult -> {
    System.out.println("async = " + asyncResult);
    System.out.println("async result = " + asyncResult.result());
    System.out.println("async failed = " + asyncResult.failed());
    System.out.println("async succeeded = " + asyncResult.succeeded());
    System.out.println("async cause = " + asyncResult.cause());
};
webClient.get(443, "oauth.vk.com", "/access_token").
    addQueryParam("client_id", appId).
    addQueryParam("client_secret", secureKey).
    addQueryParam("v", apiVersion)
    addQueryParam("grant_type", "client_credentials").
    ssl(true).
    send(testHandler);
```

It works on my local machine (Windows 10), but it fails on Ubuntu (`17.04 x64`) server. `asyncResult.failed()` is `true`. However `asyncResult.cause()` is `null`.

I tested this using cURL and it works fine; looks like a problem with Vert.x and OpenSSL interaction.

This is an excerpt of my Maven's POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try "trust all"? Also, try hooking up a debugger to drill into the root cause (e.g. perhaps a cipher issue)

Comment: @opyate `clientOptions.setTrustAll(true);` makes no difference, either `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. And it is not secure. I'm looking up for `setTrustOptions` docs. I hope remote debugging helps me.

Comment: @opyate Took important thing with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`: _System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null' System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'_  on server startup.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Vertx.vertx().createHttpClient().get(new RequestOptions().setSsl(true).setHost("oauth.vk.com").setPort(443).setURI("/access_token"), 
            res -> {
                System.out.println("result: " + res.statusCode() + " " + res.statusMessage());
                res.bodyHandler(body -> {
                    System.out.println("result body: " + body.toString());
                });
            }).end();
```